# Who is RakthaChamundi Devi

Tags: devi, kali, shaktism

Would like to know about RakthaChamundi goddess. 
Is this Devi different from Chamunda Devi?

Seems, there are multiple forms of Chamunda. Does this RakthaChamundi,  another fiercefull avatar of Chamunda?

Does this devi has any comparison with Goddess Kali